# qUnit testing for jQuery closure

Tags: jquery, sinon, qunit

I have trouble in executing qUnit for a code with a closure.

Quick overview, i am running qUnit 2.5.0 and sinon 4.3.0.

`sinon` cannot detect `iWantToTestThisOne_1()` function from both `JsFileToTest_1.js` and `JsFileToTest_2.js` files.

So right now, i can't get a hold of this closure thing

Other thing is that in `JsFileToTest_2.js` isn't even a closure but is only an `alias` of `$(document).ready(function{});`. still sinon can't detect the functions inside it.

As what i understand `sinons` takes the methods from `window` object. As i check the `window` object. The functions defined in `JsFileToTest_2`.js`and`JsFileToTest_2.js` was not attached to it.

However, when i try to remove `(function($) { })(jQuery);` and `$(function() {});`, The functions were already attached to `window` object.

My question is how can i execute a qUnit testing given that the functions are contain in either a closure `(function($) { })(jQuery);` or `$(function() {});`. I have trouble understanding how functions are attached. Also, it maybe because i have not quite got the grasp of stubbing the functions via sinon.

See examples below

**JsFileToTest_1.js**

```
(function($) {
    function iWantToTestThisOne_1() {
        //do something
        doSomething();
    }

    function iWantToTestThisOne_2() {
        //do something
        doSomething();
    }

    function iWantToTestThisOne_3() {
        //do something
        doSomething();
    }

    function doSomething() {
        //doing something
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**JsFileToTest_2.js**

```
$(function() {
    function iWantToTestThisOne_1() {
        //do something
        doSomething();
    }

    function iWantToTestThisOne_2() {
        //do something
        doSomething();
    }

    function iWantToTestThisOne_3() {
        //do something
        doSomething();
    }

    function doSomething() {
        //doing something
    }
});
```

qUnitTestCode.js

```
QUnit.test('iWantToTestThisOne_1()', function(assert){
    stub_doSomething = sinon.stub(window, "doSomething").returns("something");

    assert.equal(stub_doSomething.called, true, "doSomething() is called");
});

QUnit.test('iWantToTestThisOne_2()', function(assert){
    stub_doSomething = sinon.stub(window, "doSomething").returns("something");

    assert.equal(stub_doSomething.called, true, "doSomething() is called");
});

QUnit.test('iWantToTestThisOne_3()', function(assert){
    stub_doSomething = sinon.stub(window, "doSomething").returns("something");

    assert.equal(stub_doSomething.called, true, "doSomething() is called");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot test them using the code as you have it. Those functions are private to the wrapping function's scope (cannot be accessed outside of it). However, you could reorganize your code to allow this to happen:

```
// module 1
function initSomethings($) {  // <-- notice I added a name
    function iWantToTestThisOne_1() {
        //do something
        doSomething();
    }

    function iWantToTestThisOne_2() {
        //do something
        doSomething();
    }

    function iWantToTestThisOne_3() {
        //do something
        doSomething();
    }

    function doSomething() {
        //doing something
    }

    return { // give back the methods in here...
        iWantToTestThisOne_1,
        iWantToTestThisOne_2,
        iWantToTestThisOne_3,
        doSomething
        // Note that we don't have to return ALL of them, so you could keep some of them private by not returning them here
    };
};  // <-- notice that I am NOT calling the wrapper function
```

Then later, in some "main" module we can initialize our functions:

```
// "main" module
initSomething();
initAnother();
```

That takes care of your application code. For testing, we can use the return value of all the functions:

```
QUnit.test('iWantToTestThisOne_1()', function(assert){
    // Start by initializing your functions...
    let methods = initSomething();
    // Then stub it out...
    let stub_doSomething = sinon.stub(methods, "doSomething").returns("something");

    // Now you call the function you're testing:
    methods.iWantToTestThisOne_1();
    // And do your assertions
    assert.equal(stub_doSomething.called, true, "doSomething() is called");
    // more assertions...
});
```

Comment: Basically i have to modify the target source code to test right? I forgot to mention that the target source is a legacy code and under no circumstances that the code be modified. Anyways i got your point and there is no way of doing qunit without refactoring the source. I might do away with qunit with this particular instance

Comment: I see. Well, to be clear, this isn't QUnit that's the problem. You will not be able to test that could with any other testing framework either. Those internal functions are _not_ accessible outside of that closure.

Comment: ahh yes, what i meant when i say doing away with qunit is that i will do a manual test and not use any testing framework.